# Looking for fast database to objects mapper in C# for 200 000+ rows

Tags: c#, database, postgresql, hibernate

Im looking for fast database to objects mapper (postgresql db) in C# for 200 000+ rows with features like database updating rows/scheme auto updating. Generally I need to rewrite Java software to C# and looking for alternative to Java Hibernate (would be nice to have all those features but also it must be fast).

I appreciate any recommendations

Comment: [nHibernate](https://nhibernate.info/)? Though, if you really need to think performance-wise, I'd suggest not using a full-fledged ORM like EF, or nHibernate, rather go towards query result mapper tool like Dapper, of which Stackberg already mentioned.

Comment: Mapster is the fastest Mapper I know.

Answer (score 2):

if its just about performance and database to objects mapping I would recommend [Dapper](https://dapper-tutorial.net/). Dapper is about as fast as it gets. If you want full functionality with lots of documentation and examples I would recommend [Entity Framework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/).